# SDL2 bug? App does not receive external keyboard input event. (Kivy/Python on iPhone)

Tags: python, keyboard, kivy, sdl-2

I would like to add **external keyboard** operation to my app. Keyboard is working fine on the Mac/Kivy environment, but on **iPhone** (sent via **toolchain.py**), **keyboard input event is lost** **after TextInput** dialog is shown. 
In the following example, MyLayout2 can be switched to MyLayout1 by 'Enter' key, but MyLayout1 cannot be switched to MyLayout2 by 'Enter'. I thought it might be due to the SDL2 version, so I updated it to the latest version 2.0.10, but no change. Is it a **bug of SDL2**?

## Python code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window
sm = ScreenManager()
class MyLayout1(BoxLayout):
    pass
class MyLayout2(BoxLayout):
    pass
class MyScreen(Screen):
    dialog_number = 0
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.gridlayout = None
        self.gridlayout = MyLayout2()
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)
        Window.bind(on_key_up=self._keyup)
    def _keyup(self,*args):   
        print(args[2])
        if (args[2] == 40):
            if self.dialog_number == 0:
                self.button2_clicked()
            elif self.dialog_number == 1:
                self.button1_clicked()

    def button1_clicked(self, *args):
        if self.gridlayout is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.gridlayout = MyLayout2()
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.dialog_number = 0

    def button2_clicked(self, *args):
        if self.gridlayout is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.gridlayout = MyLayout1()
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.dialog_number = 1

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):  
        self.myscreen = MyScreen(name = 'myscreen') 
        sm.add_widget(self.myscreen)
        sm.current = 'myscreen'
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    myApp().run()
```

### Kivy code

```
<MyScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 10,40,10,40 
        spacing: 40 

<MyLayout1>:
    Button1:
        id: btn1
        text: '<MyLayout1> OK or ENTER key'
        on_release: root.parent.button1_clicked()  


<MyLayout2>:
    txtinput: txtinput
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: txtinput
        text: ''
        multiline: False
        focus: True
    button2:
        id:Button2
        text: '<MyLayout2> OK or ENTER key'
        on_release: root.parent.button2_clicked()  

<Button0@Button>:
<Button1@Button>:
<button2@Button>:
```

Comment: Did you definitely upgrade the sdl2 version on the device?

Comment: I think so. By "./toolchain.py recipes", I get following.  

python2      2.7.1  
python3      3.7.1   
pyyaml       3.11    
sdl2         2.0.10  
sdl2_image   2.0.4   
sdl2_mixer   2.0.4   
sdl2_ttf     2.0.14  
werkzeug     master  
zbarlight    1.2